# Force absolute URLs in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

Currently I'm using

```
<a href="{{ "/test/link/" | absolute_url }}">
```

to generate an absolute url:

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/test/link/">
```

Or

```
<img src="{{ "/test/image.png" | absolute_url }}">
```

to generate

```
<img src="https://www.example.com/test/image.png">
```

Is there a way or config setting to force using absolute urls for the entire site, without having to add the `absolute_url` filter all the time, for each `a href` or `img src` url in each page?

Comment: Why will you need to set absolute urls to reach local resources ? Because short answer is "no", but and longer answer can be "yes" with some plugin.